# Why i only see the last element of array in a table view in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface

I have a `UI` as given below and when i click save button in UI i want to add three values on top of the view to a table view, in which has three different labels for representing them and a custom structure to define the model. But my problem is that i can only append one element but what i want is to keep previously added elements in that array and show them in a `tableView`.

**Here is the UI image**

[image]

**Here is the code:**

MainViewController.swift

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var minDbLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var averageDbLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var maximumDbLabel: UILabel!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "saveRecord" {
            let recordVC = segue.destination as! RecordTableViewController

            recordVC.record.minimumValue = (minDbLabel.text! as NSString).floatValue
            recordVC.record.averageValue = (averageDbLabel.text! as NSString).floatValue
            recordVC.record.maximumValue = (maximumDbLabel.text! as NSString).floatValue

            recordVC.recordsArray.append(recordVC.record)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveRecord", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

**RecordTableViewController.swift:**

```
class RecordCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minimumValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var averageValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var maximumValueLabel: UILabel!
}

class RecordTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellIdentifier: String = "cellID"
    var recordsArray = [Record]()
    var record: Record = Record()

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRight(_:)))
        swipe.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: recordsArray.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recordsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RecordCell
        cell.minimumValueLabel.text = "\(recordsArray[indexPath.row].minimumValue)"
        cell.averageValueLabel.text = "\(recordsArray[indexPath.row].averageValue)"
        cell.maximumValueLabel.text = "\(recordsArray[indexPath.row].maximumValue)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Record.swift

```
struct Record {
    var minimumValue: Float = .nan
    var averageValue: Float = .nan
    var maximumValue: Float = .nan
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Note: I already have searched on Google to find an answer but to no avail.

Comment: A photo of a computer screen? Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should append the data in `recordsArray` in `MainViewController` first before performing the segue. See the code below

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var minDbLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var averageDbLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var maximumDbLabel: UILabel!
    var recordsArray = [Record]()


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "saveRecord" {
            let recordVC = segue.destination as! RecordTableViewController
            var record = Record()
            record.minimumValue = Float(minDbLabel.text!) ?? 0.0
            record.averageValue = Float(averageDbLabel.text!) ?? 0.0
            record.maximumValue = Float(maximumDbLabel.text!) ?? 0.0
            self.recordsArray.append(record)
            recordVC.recordsArray = self.recordsArray
        }
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveRecord", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

Just replace your `MainViewController` with the code above and it should work.

Comment: in viewDidLoad() print to check if your recordsArray has received the value or not.

Comment: print(recordsArray) inside RecordTableView's viewDidLoad prints the last element

Comment: you are not doing it write. update your latest code in question

Comment: how are you coming back from `RecordTableViewController` to `MainViewController` . show that code

Comment: With a swipe gesture

Comment: No, i mean using pop or dismiss. can you show the code please?

Comment: Swipe gesture kind is **show** and here is the code: objc func swipeRight(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
  switch gesture.direction {
   case .right:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "swipeRight", sender: nil)
   default:
   break
  }
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205588/discussion-between-theguardiandevil-and-iosarchitect-com).